# Ubuntu newb: no screen signal after install of Desktop 18.04.3

Tags: 18.04, graphics

Absolute newb here, having problems with my first install. I've made a bootable USB stick with the installer for Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.3. When I boot on the stick, I get the simple text menu, allowing me to try or install Ubuntu. If I choose Install, the signal to my screen dies. Instead, I tried the option to Try Ubuntu without installing, and it took me to the GUI without any problems.. From there, I chose the option to install Ubuntu to a local SSD, and the installation process seemed to complete without any problems. When re-booting on the disk I just installed to, I again loose the signal to my monitor, and have nothing but a blank screen. Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you have Windows and your intent is to 1) create a dual boot machine or 2) replace Windows with Ubuntu, please open a Command Prompt in Windows and do `wmic computersystem get manufacturer,model,systemtype` then copy the result, return here, click [edit] and paste the result into your question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem went away on its own after a couple of hours, I watched a movie on Netflix for a few hours on a different PC, and when I switched my KVN-switch back to the Ubuntu machine, the problem haddisappeared. Looks like it was something related to my KVM-switch, rather than the Ubuntu install.